# Rails: cannot add column through migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have this simple migration:

```
class AddUpdateStatusToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :products, :update_status, :integer, :default => 0
  end
end
```

`rake db:migrate` produce this error:

```
rake aborted!
/Users/adam/rubydev/project_name/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:90: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Where's the problem? The table name is correct, the syntax of migration should be as well...

Comment: There is some syntax error in `project_name/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake` not in migration. Can you check or post that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this file: `/Users/adam/rubydev/project_name/lib/tasks/scheduler`
which you forgot to put end or } somewhere there around the line 90